# Combine two SQL queries - COUNT and WHERE

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to combine these two SQL Queries to show the username with the highest count of 1's in the access column that also has an itemID of 2 AND Access of 1.

How would I combine these two statements to produce this result?

Show the account with the highest permissions:

```
SELECT UserName, COUNT(Access) AS Count 
FROM Permissions
GROUP BY UserName, Access
HAVING Access = 1
ORDER BY Count DESC

Result:
Username    AccessCount
user1       2
user2       1
user3       2
```

Show all accounts with Data Manager access:

```
SELECT UserName FROM Permissions
where itemid = 2 AND Access = 1

Result:
Username
user1
user2
```

Permissions table sample data:

```
itemID  UserName    Access
1       user1       1
2       user1       1
3       user1       1
1       user2       0
2       user2       1
3       user2       0
1       user3       1
2       user3       0
3       user3       1
```

The result would be user1 as they have access on itemID 2 and the highest count of access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQLFiddle demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7e5de/3)

```
SELECT TOP 1 UserName, COUNT(Access) AS Count 
FROM Permissions ps
WHERE Access = 1
AND
userNAme in 
     (SELECT UserName 
        FROM Permissions
         where itemid = 2 
           AND Access = 1
      )
GROUP BY UserName
ORDER BY Count DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM 
(
SELECT [USERNAME] as un,COUNT(ACCESS) AS COUNT
FROM Permissions    
GROUP BY USERNAME,ACCESS
HAVING ACCESS=1     
) a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT [USERNAME] FROM Permissions WHERE [USERNAME]=a.un and itemid=2)
ORDER BY COUNT DESC
```